# Am I entitled to a refund from Lenovo if I don't accept the installation of Windows?

Tags: laptop, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I return a Microsoft License delivered with a Dell computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/391037/how-can-i-return-a-microsoft-license-delivered-with-a-dell-computer)

I'm in the process of upgrading the kit in my home office. I've upgraded my server and PC as well as my wireless router. The next bit of kit I need to replace is my ThinkPad R50e which I've had since 2005. Since 2006 however it has ran Linux and not Windows.

While I've been shopping around, I am hoping to get another ThinkPad as the one I have at the moment has been good to me and never let me down. However, when I've gone on to the ThinkPad website, I'm unable to buy a laptop without having Windows installed on it. As I won't be using Windows on it and Linux will be thrown on there as soon as the power button is pressed, I'm really paying extra money for something I don't need. I've spoken to Lenovo by email and asked them if it was possible to buy a laptop that either has Linux pre-installed or no operating system installed at all. They said no, so I'd have to run Windows.

But when you buy a new laptop you are given a EULA, and really if you don't accept the terms & conditions set out in it aren't you entitled to give the software back for a refund? Or does this not apply in terms of operating systems and laptops?

Comment: @bob I agree. But the question that springs to mind is: Why bother? Spending hours defying a system just to save a few bucks is a waste of time and money.

Comment: @user99572isfine Would you go to a restaurant and pay £30 for a three course meal when you only wanted a starter? No you wouldn't. I don't like paying for things I don't want or need. It might sound tight, but it's absolutely pointless paying for things you don't need or use.

Comment: @mickburkejnr you're morally right. I am just advocating the pragmatic approach. But SU is not the place to discuss these questions. Here's another answer that might help you:  http://superuser.com/questions/29799/any-good-cheap-linux-or-no-operating-system-computer-sellers-in-the-us

Comment: You are not forced to buy a PC from Lenovo, you can build one yourself and avoid the Windows tax. You would have to take Lenovo to court, prove you did not accept the Windows licence terms to get a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you haven't accepted the EULA (or clicked no) The EULA say's you're entitled but should contact the manufacturer. The liklihood of getting one varies depending on who the manufacturer is. You will also need to prove you haven't accepted - a photo will normally suffice

Comment: Cheers for this, I will do this when I buy the laptop.